# How can I use eclipse to build a GUI? (I want to use only swing/awt and no other packages)

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, ide

I usually write java code using a simple text editor and .bat files to compile and run. I'm not used to IDEs like Eclipse or Netbeans and as a result every GUI I've made so far has been written by hand.

Questions:

- Can I use eclipse to build a GUI easily (e.g. drag-drop features)?
- Can this generated code use only the basic java packages (swing, awt) and not any other package provided by the IDE?

I'm saying this because -correct me if I'm wrong- from what I have read so far, I understand that Eclipse and other IDEs use their own packages (to achieve better layouts for example). I would like to avoid this dependency and if possible copy-paste the code generated by Eclipse and then work in the simple way I'm used to.

Thanks in advance.

**[edit]**
Having tried it for a couple of days, I can now say that **WindowsBuilder** is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for all your replies.

Comment: Can you kindly explain how you went about creating swing-based UI elements using Windowbuilder in eclipse? I've just started using eclipse and all it does is create org.eclipse.swt.widget controls. If I create swing elements, it puts them under **(non-visual beans)** category and doesn't display them when I run the app. Working in C# was piece of cake. This eclipse thingy has brought me to the brim of madness :( Nothing, absolutely NOTHING seems to work. For Java GUI, I have now tried NetBeans, Eclipse, SceneBuilder, Visual Studio code and nothing at all works like Visual Studio does for C#.

Comment: Hey @NoorulAin, this is an old post from 2012. I really don't know how things might have evolved. One thing I would do, is dig a little bit to the [most voted questions tagged with `java` and `swing`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java%2bswing?tab=Votes) because this might shed some light and as a last resort ask a new question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eclipse uses the Standard Widget Toolkit (SWT, not included in JRE by default), Netbeans uses Swing (included).
Since recent Eclipse versions, it includes [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) to create Swing or SWT via drag'n'drop. WindowBuilder is even bidirectional, so code generation is supported as well as reflecting hand-made changes. It don't know if Netbeans includes this feature, too. In 'New' dialog of Eclipse you find everything you need under the WindowBuilder category.

Comment: I've used both Netbeans and WindowBuilder on Eclipse for swing dev (for relatively complex situations) - and my projects have settled on Eclipse WindowBuilder because it is bi-directional.

Comment: It should be added that WindowBuilder fulfills the questioner's requirement that GUIs built with it don't use any additional libraries.

Answer (score 5):

Yes , You can use the feature of drag and Drop in java by going through these few Steps:

<kbd>Help</kbd> → <kbd>Eclipse MarketPlace</kbd> → <kbd>WindowBuilder(Install)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

> Can I use eclipse to build a GUI easily (e.g. drag-drop features)?

Yes, go to the Marketplace and pull in WindowsBuilder; it supports bi-directional GUI drag-n-drop / direct-code editing.

> Can this generated code use only the basic java packages (swing, awt) and not any other package provided by the IDE?

The code generated by the Swing Design tool is strictly Swing/AWT based.

It does offer design tools for SWT and GWT as well.

Comment: It should be noted that this is no longer accessible on the Eclipse marketplace. Go here https://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create Drag n Drop Swing GUI, you should try Netbeans. Eclipse may have a plugin but i usually find netbeans very good in GUI and it is also recommended by Sun for making Swing/AWT GUI

Comment: the only downside is that the generated code is locked and can't be editted.... unless they changed that?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen such in Eclipse. In Netbeans you can of course. But I am warning you! Create the GUI by hand. Netbeans is using GroupLayout to build drag and drop GUI, and that's a nightmare when you look at it!!! If eclipse has the same function, don't expect more than this!! Apart from that, not like .NET, most Java developers create everything by hand (Yes, real programming..That's why most say Java is hard). So, it is better if you can get used to it :)